# Difference between PHP 5.6u and PHP 5.6w

Tags: php, linux, yum

I've been going through running PHP 5.6 and now looking at 7 running on CentOS 7 (typically 5.4) and I had been installing php56u and now I've been seeing php56w and I can't find anywhere what the difference is.

Comment: Good question and answer, but shouldn't this be in a section other than Stack Overflow? This seems more like software related.

Comment: Fair point, as it's a programming language rather than just a service like Apache I think it could go into either. ie, if the u or w was associated to a particular build parameter that affected lets say deprecated functions than it would just belong here.

Comment: Yeah, either/or. It's definitely php related though, that's a "for sure". Maybe adding another tag for it? TBH I don't know which one. "Environment" maybe and/or "operating system"? It would need a more specific and give the question better coverage / attention.

Comment: I've added a couple more tags, I'm hesitant to put ones that relate to knowing what the answer was before posting the question though.

Comment: *Aye,* right you are. *cheers*

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww please read the above thread and please stop with the passive aggressive post when this has been already discussed, it doesn't help the community.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The last letter represents some sort of informal way of designating the origin of a third party release of `PHP`:

```
php56u = IUS Repository
php56w = Webtatic Repository
```

Both third party repositories compiled the source tarballs of `PHP 5.6` and publicly released the package, appending a letter to its name in order to differentiate it from the official CentOS' one.

This practice doesn't represent a golden standard and every third party repository can use a different convention for releasing packages. The same `PHP` version released by Software Collections, for example, is named `rh-php56`.

Comment: Is it best to keep it the same (ie if on u stay with u) or is there really no difference?

Comment: I think you can switch between one and another without any sort of problems. It's just the same source code compiled by different hands, after all.

Comment: @TommasoBelluzzo no, build environment and used libraries may result in different binaries (feature, perf...) ex: https://twitter.com/RemiRepository/status/955740534416510976